# Javascript: Edit ID3 tags of mp3

Tags: javascript, mp3, id3

I have a blob data of an mp3 downloaded from server using XMLHttpReqest in my web application. I want to edit the ID3 tags of the file (i.e. edit album art, genre, artist, album etc.). I checked by there are libraries that can read ID3 tags in javascript but didn't find any implementation about editing them in javascript. I want to do this in web browser, I have no option to do this on server. The server is just an external cdn server storing mp3 files.

Comment: googling `node id3` outputs many libraries

Comment: Nope I don't want in node

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cw7w5/ + http://id3.org/ID3v1

Comment: Most of the node (npm) package can be run in a browser context also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library helps writing id3 tags: https://github.com/egoroof/browser-id3-writer

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still looking for this kind of library, [mp3tag.js](https://github.com/eidoriantan/mp3tag.js) can read and write ID3 tags.