# edit metadata of music file like lyrics, artist ,album and description mainly (add custom tags also if possible )

Tags: angular, typescript, metadata

I used `jsmediatags` to access metadata ( as [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362536/brad) suggested earlier in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76696678/extract-album-cover-from-mp3-file-with-out-using-any-external-third-party-lib-o)  ) but now i want to edit these fields and let the user add some tags that are missing, as most of the time lyrics are not available in many music files.

```ts
jsmediatags.read(file, {
  onSuccess: (tag) => {
    tag.tags.lyrics ='my lyrics updated ... !'
    // also
    tag.tags.TXXX[0].description ='my another description...!'
    //but what do next ? what will be the proper way
    // i am getting some idea with ID3 but not clearly
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% clear on what your question is here. It sounds like you want to be able to use this `jsmediatags` library to write/change/update data in the files you are reading from right now.

I assume this is the project page for the library you are talking about:
https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags

If so, a quick look at their docs and code examples shows that the library is only for reading tags, not writing them. The description of the project is "Media Tags Reader (ID3, MP4, FLAC)" so I think this is the wrong project for what you want to do. You will need to find another project that allow you to write back to your files.

Comment: yes it is the same lib that you mentioned and i am using it to extract meta information  . i can use different lib for this purpose (editing meta data )  . what will be your suggestion on that

Comment: A quick google for "javascript edit MP3 Tags" pointed me to this question which probably has the info you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662843/javascript-edit-id3-tags-of-mp3

Comment: sounds useful . thank you mr. barr :)